# Change the year in a datetime object in R?

Tags: r, date

I have the following:

```
"0014-06-30"
```

And I'd like to change it to:

```
"0000-06-30"
```

How would I do this in R?

Everything that I'm reading is very focused on converting strings to dates rather than changing around the elements inside a date.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
> x <- as.Date('0014-06-30')
> x
[1] "0014-06-30"
> library(lubridate)
> year(x)
[1] 14
> year(x) <- 0
> x
[1] "0000-06-30"
```

Comment: I get `x <- as.Date('0014-06-30'); x#[1] "14-06-30"`

Comment: @akrun interesting... I just verified my output above from a fresh R session. Don't know what the difference could be.

Comment: I tried on a fresh console as well.  No difference.  Anyway, plus one for the method

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the specific format by converting to `as.Date`.  A `regex` option would be

```
str1 <- "0014-06-30"
as.Date(str1)
#[1] "14-06-30"

sub('\\d{2}(?=-)', '00', str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "0000-06-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would offer the following function to fix a mixed vector of two and four digit dates (where you have have formatted a string as a date if starting with a string):

```
library(lubridate)
two_dig_year_cnvt <- function(z, year=2017){
    y <- as.numeric(format(z, '%Y'))
    range <- 2017 - 2000
    year(z) <- ifelse(y >= 0 & y <= range, 2000 + y, 
                      ifelse(y > range & y <= 200, 1900 + y, y))
    z
}
```

This says for two digit years 00-16, assume that 2000 was the intended century, and for years 17-200 assume the century was 1900. Else, return the original year. If you're dealing with 19th century dates then of course this method is a no-go.